# How to correctly denote geomethric plane in $R^3$ using vector span?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I learned to denote lines like following, where $\vec{p}$ is direction vector, $P$ is point in the line and `< >` is the notation for linear span of vector(s):

$$p: X = P + <\vec{p}>$$

This is meant to be equivalent to:

$$p: X = P + t\cdot\vec{p},\ t\in R$$

Now a plane with point $P$ and vectors $\vec{p},\vec{q}$ can be written as:

$$\rho:\ X = P + t\cdot\vec{p}+u\cdot\vec{q},\ t,u\in R$$

And I would be inclined to write it as:

$$\rho:\ X = P + <\{\vec{p}, \vec{q}\}>$$

Is that correct? I have no other reasons to use linear span than laziness (no need to define $t$ and remember not to use that letter any more) and the fact that I find it more obvious.

Comment: Looks alright. Perhaps you could choose to simplify to $\langle \vec p, \vec q \rangle$ since you didn't put the $\vec p$ in a set (singleton) in the case of the line either.

Comment: For a more  pedantic flavour, you could write $\{P\} + \operatorname{sp} \{ p,q \}$.